# Update document that contain TTL with reseting the TTL

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a document, that last 120 seconds, and as soon as i call this method i want the TTL to restart.

At the moment i can"t update my document, after 120 sc .. the document get deleted and re-created instead of being always updated.

There is my collection :

```
LaptopConnections = new Mongo.Collection('laptopConnection');

let LaptopConnectionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Date when the laptop was created",
    defaultValue: Date.now
  },

  "state.date": {
    type: Date,
    label: "time when the laptop was updated",
    autoValue: function () {
      return new Date;
    }
  }
}
  , { timestamps: true }
)
LaptopConnections.attachSchema(LaptopConnectionSchema)
```

And there is my method :

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    LapConnections._ensureIndex({ creationDate: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 120 });// Will delete the collection after ~~ two minutes,

});
Meteor.methods({

  create_lapconnection(lap_id) {
    check(lap_id, String);
    if (!LapConnections.findOne({ _id: lap_id })) {
      console.log('workiiing',lap_id)
      LaptopConnections.insert({
        _id: box_id,
        creationDate: Date.now(),
      });
    } else {
      console.log('updated',lap_id)
      LaptopConnections.update({ _id: lap_id }, { upsert: true }, {
        $set: {
          "state.date": Date.now(),
        }
      }
      );

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the `state.date` field while your index sits on the `creationDate` field. Once you update `creationDate` or change your index to use the `state.date` field instead it should work.